# How do i get the web browser password store to remember R/Shiny passwords?

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

## The problem

I have a shiny application that requires user to login to access the underlying dataset.

The username and password are collected from form fields and submitted via a RESTful API on another server to get an access token which is used in future requests.  I haven't included those details in this example.

[image]

I want to get the web browser to remember the login details and login automatically, but can't quite see how.

## What I tried

In my first implementation, the `<input type="text" name="username">` and `<input type="password" name="password">` plus an `actionButton` were dynamically added to the page.  This forced the user to re-login each time the shiny application was restarted, which was complex for development and unpleasant for users.

I then found https://gist.github.com/kostiklv/968927 which details the conditions for having the web browser remember the password and log in.

Shiny works on one page, so I couldn't have a separate login page (this would generate a new shiny session, discarding the login!).

I have tried various combinations of things, here is the closest I have got.  This script correctly fills in a past password, but the user still has to manually hit submit.

## Example code

**Note that I have a custom hack my shiny in to enable `type="password"` to be treated the same as `type="text"`.  See bottom of question for access to this code**

save this code as `login.R` then run `R` and type `source("login.R")`

```
write("","blank.html")
require(shiny)
addResourcePath("login",tools:::file_path_as_absolute("./"))
runApp(list(
  ui=bootstrapPage(
    tags$form(action="#",target="loginframe",
      tags$input(id="username",type="text",placeholder="Username"),
      tags$input(id="password",type="password",placeholder="Password"),
      tags$input(id="loginButton",class="btn btn-primary",type="submit",value="Login")
    ),
    tags$iframe(name="loginframe",src="login/blank.html",style="display:none")
  ),
  server=function(input, output) {
    observe({message(
        "username ",input$username,"\n",
        "password ",input$password,"\n"
    )})
  })
)
```

## Analysis of what happened

Note that the presence of an html `input submit button` seems to tell shiny that it should only update the inputs once every submit.  Without the submit button shiny updates its inputs every keystroke.

The same is true for shiny's `submitButton`.

Leaving the form but removing the button allows input$username and input$password to reach the server code, but...

To enable both conventional user login and automated login, I need the button to avoid repeated attempts to authenticate (which might cause problems) for partial usernames and passwords.

## Log of what happened

Here are the console logs from the tests

### Log with a submit button:

```
username 
password 
<enter username AA and password BB>
*no update*
<hit submit>
*browser requests to save password / yes*
username A
password B
<refresh page>
username 
password
* onscreen form inputs are populated *
<hit submit>
username A
password B
```

### Log without a submit button

Comment out 
      tags$input(id="loginButton",class="btn btn-primary",type="submit",value="Login")
and the preceding comma

*note you may want to tell your browser to forget localhost web passwords for now.*

```
username
password
<enter username AA and password BB>
username A
password
username AA
password
username AA
password B
password BB
<refresh browser>
* onscreen form inputs are not populated *
* browser requests to save password *
username
password
<refresh browser>
* onscreen form inputs are populated *
username
password
username AA
username BB
```

---

## Shiny patch to enable password handling:

Install using `library(devtools)`

```
install_github("shiny","alexbbrown",ref="password-field")
```

Or download and install manually:

```
https://github.com/alexbbrown/shiny.git (branch password-field)
```

Or patch your shiny manually:

```
index 9b63c7b..15377d8 100644
--- a/inst/www/shared/shiny.js
+++ b/inst/www/shared/shiny.js
@@ -1336,7 +1336,7 @@
   var textInputBinding = new InputBinding();
   $.extend(textInputBinding, {
     find: function(scope) {
-      return $(scope).find('input[type="text"]');
+      return $(scope).find('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]');
     },
     getId: function(el) {
       return InputBinding.prototype.getId.call(this, el) || el.name;
```

cf [Password field using R Shiny framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870449/password-field-using-r-shiny-framework?rq=1)

Comment: It seems like I'm not getting a 'click'.  any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered adding authentication in top of shiny (using nginx or apache, or node.js) ? It is easy, robust and well tested

Comment: functionality you are talking about is related to cookie management . You can use javascript for this

Comment: Yeah, so, what Karl Says.  When I ran a shiny server, I used authentication via Apache.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html.  Aside from that, it sounds like you are trail blazing.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for something similar, and trestletech's fantastic package `shinyStore` worked for me.

It enables HTML5 client-side data storage for any data in your shiny app.

The github page is [here](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore), and an example of how it works is [here](https://trestletech.shinyapps.io/ss-01-persist/).

You may wish to read the "Security" section on the README and ensure it is secure enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can use `postForm()` from `RCurl` package to perform a regular HTTP form submit request (unless `Shiny` would interfere with this functionality, which is based on using underlying `libcurl` library). For an example code, please see function `srdaLogin()` in my R module "getSourceForgeData.R": https://github.com/abnova/diss-floss/blob/master/import/getSourceForgeData.R.